# DRF Update or Create TypeError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a structure where a list of books read is kept. I had set up a structure, but if the read finished statement is checked, it adds a new record. What I want to do is to create only 1 record according to that user and book id value and constantly update this record. When I want to do this, I get the following error, I cannot access the book id value. There are many similar questions, but I couldn't make the right application, I need suggestions.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1823, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Book'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\bookorbooks\book\api\views\reading_history_views.py", line 32, in perform_create
    obj_lst = ReadingHistory.objects.filter(book=book, child=child)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1347, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1193, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 117, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "E:\!Staj\bookorbooks\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Book: Example Book 1>.
```

**Model**

```
class ReadingHistory(AbstractBookBaseModel):
    IS_FINISHED = ((False,
                    BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_false),
                   (True, BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_true))
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        "book.Book",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="book_reading_history",
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.book_verbose_name)
    child = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.ChildProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child_reading_history",
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.child_verbose_name)
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(
        choices=IS_FINISHED,
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_verbose_name
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.child.user.first_name} {self.child.user.last_name} - \"{self.book.name}\" "
```

**Serializer**

```
class ReadingHistoryCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReadingHistory
        exclude = ["child"]

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     """
    #         If the user wants to add the same student to a class for the second time, it will throw an error.
    #     """
    #     created = self.Meta.model.objects.get(child = validated_data["child"], book = validated_data["book"])
    #     if not created:
    #         instance = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
    #         return instance
    #     else:
    #         is_finished_value = created.is_finished
    #         if is_finished_value == validated_data["is_finished"]:
    #             pass
    #         else:
    #             obj = self.Meta.model.objects.update(child = validated_data["child"], book = validated_data["book"], is_finished = validated_data["is_finished"])
    #             return obj
```

**View**

```
class AddReadingHistoryAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ReadingHistory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReadingHistoryCreateSerializer

    # def perform_create(self, serializer):
    #     return serializer.save(child=self.request.user.user_child)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        book = serializer.validated_data.get('book', ),
        is_finished = serializer.validated_data.get('is_finished', )
        child = self.request.user.user_child
        obj_lst = ReadingHistory.objects.filter(book=int(book), child=child)
        if obj_lst:
            obj_lst.update(is_finished=is_finished)
        else:
            ReadingHistory.objects.create(book=book,
                                          child=child,
                                          is_finished=is_finished)
```

Comment: Try `book=book.id`

Comment: @bdbd I already tried this, but it returns none

Comment: Isn't the ID of the book accessed by book.pk ?

Comment: @dustin-we I typed it as book.pk instead of book.id and it worked. But I don't understand why book.id works everywhere else but not here.